# C++ ifstream reads a non existing newline at the end

Tags: c++, c++11

I made a basic C++ program to read a one line text file that does not include any newline character which looks like this:

```
ifstream ifs;
ifs.open(filename);
char c;
int cint;
while (ifs >> noskipws >> c) {
    cint = c;
    cout << "'" << c << "' = " << cint << endl;
}
```

The thing is; while it reads everything that I wanted it also reads a non-existing newline character at the end which prints 10 for its ASCII number. I am using g++ and I deleted the file and rewrote basic test cases but it always gets a newline character at the end. What may be the reason for it?

Comment: how do you create/fill the input file ? what is the result when you do in a terminal `cat file`, do you get the prompt on the same line of the last line of the file ? if the prompt after the command in alone on its line that means your file finishes by a newline

Comment: How certain are you that the file does not have a newline? How did you create the file? Is the file size the same as the number of characters you think are in the file?

Comment: I explain more my previous remark in an answer

Comment: _"a non-existing newline character"_ Are you sure?

Comment: Your editor is adding a newline even though you didn't type one.

Comment: Do it like bruno in his answer and *show us the data.*

Comment: If you're on Linux or otherwise have GNU tools, you could compare to the results of `od -t u1` _filename_

Comment: I tried both gedit and nano and trusted their display to actually think the file doesn't contain newline character, since for some reason while they added newline they didn't show it on editor, thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you certainly have a newline at the end of your input file

using :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  ifstream ifs;
  ifs.open("/tmp/i");
  char c;
  int cint;
  while (ifs >> noskipws >> c) {
    cint = c;
    cout << "'" << c << "' = " << cint << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

compilation, execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -Wall f.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cat > i
123
456
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
'1' = 49
'2' = 50
'3' = 51
'
' = 10
'4' = 52
'5' = 53
'6' = 54
'
' = 10
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cat i
123
456
pi@raspberrypi:
```

my way to create the file placed a newline at the end of each line, so a final newline, and the use of the command *cat* also shows it.

Now I add a last line non terminated by a newline :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ echo -n "wxc" >> i
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cat i
123
456
wxcpi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ 
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
'1' = 49
'2' = 50
'3' = 51
'
' = 10
'4' = 52
'5' = 53
'6' = 54
'
' = 10
'w' = 119
'x' = 120
'c' = 99
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

and as you can see no unexpected final newline is read, and the use of the command *cat* writes the prompt after the last line of the file rather than on its line alone (`wxcpi@raspberrypi:/tmp $`)

Also :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cp /dev/null i
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

That means the way you created/fill your input file put a final newline in your file, may be using an editor that one forced that final newline